# AdMob ignores to if/else statements for iPhone app

Tags: ios, admob, iad

i seem to have implemented iad/admob mediation correctly because it works in viewDidLoad. However, in my GameOver method, AdMob doesn't pay attention to if/else statements at all.

```
if (self.admobBannerView.hidden==YES) {


   self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 60.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.bannerView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
      [self.bannerView setAlpha:1];

    self.bannerView.hidden=NO;

}
else


    [self.bannerView setAlpha:0];
  self.bannerView.hidden=YES;

admobBannerView=[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];


self.admobBannerView.adUnitID = @"unit-id0";
self.admobBannerView.rootViewController = self;
self.admobBannerView.delegate = self;


[self.view addSubview:self.admobBannerView];

GADRequest *request =[GADRequest request];

request.testDevices= @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];

[self.admobBannerView loadRequest:request];
 }
```

The above is in my GameOver method and AdMob ignores it completely and ONLY shows AdMob ads. iAd is never played in GameOver. Is AdMob not supposed to pay attention to if/else statements?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (self.admobBannerView.hidden==YES) {


   self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 60.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.bannerView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
      [self.bannerView setAlpha:1];

    self.bannerView.hidden=NO;

}
else


    [self.bannerView setAlpha:0];
  self.bannerView.hidden=YES;
```

this is the same as:

```
if (self.admobBannerView.hidden==YES) {


   self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 60.0f, 320.0f, 50.0f)];
    [self.bannerView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
      [self.bannerView setAlpha:1];

    self.bannerView.hidden=NO;

}
else
{
    [self.bannerView setAlpha:0];
}
  self.bannerView.hidden=YES;
```

Comment: formatting your code will sometime give you the answer, because it looks like yours is all over the place.

Comment: That was my fault, i shouldn't have added the } at the end. That's for end of the entire GameOver method. Nothing wrong with my formatting, just accidentally added it here. However, still makes no difference, AdMob still dominates.